# Select inner quotes that are between quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I wonder if you can help me with to figure out the regex to match inner quotes that are between quotes.

My problem is that I have an invalid JSON file that looks like

```
{
   "name" : "some "name" here",
   "lastName" : "some "lastname" here"
}
```

As you may notice the inner double quotes are not escaped and I have an array with hundreds of records and some of them have that problem.
(I know that an invalid JSON cannot be read, so I am using fs from Node to get the string version of the JSON file)

```
fs.readFileSync('./bigJSON.json','utf8')
```

I made this regex

```
/(?:\w\s)\".*\"(?:\s\w)/g
```

that matches (e "name" h) and (e "lastname" h).
I wonder if there is a way to only target the nested quotes (").

I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Use something like `s.replace(/(\s*:\s*")(.*)"/g, function($0,$1,$2) {return $1 + $2.replace(/"/g, "") + '"';})`

Comment: So, you can use a regex on a string not an object.  Is your target a JSON representation of that object, or perhaps just the name/lastname properties are the values you're working with?  Can you show us what the string you are trying to perform this regex query on actually looks like please?

Comment: it's a 130 mb JSON file man, what I wrote in my question is an example

Comment: Right but we can't do anything with that object because it's invalid and will throw an error.  I'm trying to figure out if the property names are part of your string or if you are only dealing with the property values for this question.

Comment: the way I am reading it is using fs from Node fs.readFileSync('./bigJSON.json','utf8') which returns an stringified version, I am dealing with property values

Comment: OK so just to clarify, bigJSON.json contains invalid JSON and you want to clean it up before calling JSON.parse or similar?  Are you reading the file line by line and operating on each line?

Comment: That's right @James

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that regex is not good at finding unknown amounts of things.

This will find the first two unescaped quotes within a quoted string using negative lookbehinds

```
\"(?<!\\).*(\"(?<!\\)).*(\"(?<!\\)).*\"(?<!\\)
```

where the two capture groups contain the offending unescaped quotes.  A slightly safer version would be

```
\"(?<!\\).*\"(?<!\\) : \"(?<!\\).*(\"(?<!\\)).*(\"(?<!\\)).*\"(?<!\\),?(?:\n|\r|\r\n)
```

but requires your data to be fairly consistent.  This could be run multiple times, removing the found offending quotes until no more are found.

I would suggest that the best way to do this would be programmatically, as regex is no good at this, possibly as simply as reading the file character-by-character.

**Update**
Just noticed you are using Javascript.  According to http://regexr.com/, Javascript does not support positive or negative lookbehinds, although you should be correcting your file once before it is needed so could use any language.